# In flex container, does block element (as flex item) act exactly same as inline-block element? any difference?

Tags: css, flexbox, display

```
<style>
.parent {
    display:flex;
}
.child {
    
}
</style>


<div class='parent'>
   <div class='child'>Hello</div>
</div>
```

Here's what I thought, block-level elements have 100% width (including margin), but in flex container, block-level flex item gets width that is the content's width of an item.
That's the same trait of an inline-block elements.
So, I don't know what the differences are between 'block' and 'inline-block' as a flex item.

Comment: There's no such thing as a block-level flex item. Flex items are [flex-level](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-level)

Answer (score -1):

A block element takes up the full width of its parent container by default, whereas an inline-block element only takes up as much width as its content requires. This means that a block element will always be the full width of the flex container, whereas an inline-block element will only be as wide as its content.

Another difference is that block elements will create a new line after them by default, whereas inline-block elements will be placed next to each other on the same line.

In a flex container, however, both block and inline-block elements can be set to flex items, and they will both respond to the flex container's properties such as flex-wrap, align-items, etc. The only difference is that a block element will take up the full width of the container while an inline-block element will take the width of its content.